# How to add a hardcoded record to query result set in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have BookController, where it has relationship to author and publisher tables.

I need to add a publisher record on the fly , hardcoded in the code, that will show as a secondary publisher for the book. This is kind a default I need to use.

I am not sure how in Laravel, the bookController can do this?

Comment: Can you present what you have done so far to go according to your idea?

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that a book has (at least) two publishers? In that case you could setup your relationships like this:

**publishers** | m ------m | **books** | m----1 | **author**

Then when adding the `publisher A` to a book, you add the `publisher A` but also the `publisher Z` (the "harcoded" one). So then when you need to query the publishers for a book just return:

```
$book = App\book::find(1);
$book->publishers;
```

Comment: Thanks HCK. But how to add the publisher to the book? Sorry, I am trying to edit the code that is written by someone else, and I need to find where in the code I may need to do the changes.

Comment: In my example, Books to Publishers are a many-to-many relationship, you can relate many `Publisher` objects to a `Book` one with the `saveMany()` method. Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method).

Comment: Or share some of the code you are having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Books Model:

```
public function getPublishersAttribute()
{
    $publishers= $this->publishers()->get(); // call the relationship and get collection
    $new_publisher = new Publisher(); // create a new hardcoded publisher and set the data without saving
    return $publishers->add($new_publisher);
}
```

Now you can get the publishers collection ( plus the hardcoded publisher) by calling:
`$book->publishers;`